# CakePHP passing values between controllers

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to pass values from one controller to another.
For example I have a Conference controller and I want to create a new Event.
I want to pass the Conference id to the event to make sure those two objects are associated.
I would like to store in the ivar $conference using beforeFilter method.

Here is my beforeFilter function in the Events controller

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    echo '1 ' + $this->request->id;
    echo '2 ' +     $this->request['id'];
    echo $this->request->params['id'];
            if(isset(   $this->request->params['id'])){
             $conference_id =   $this->request->params['id'];       
        }
        else{
         echo "Id Doesn't Exist";   
        }   
}
```

Whenever I change url to something like:

```
http://localhost:8888/cake/events/id/3
```

or

```
http://localhost:8888/cake/events/id:3
```

I am getting an error saying that id is not defined.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you're passing data via url you can access it via

```
$this->passedArgs['variable_name'];
```

For example if your URL is:

```
http://localhost/events/id:7
```

Then you access that id with this line

```
$id = $this->passedArgs['id'];
```

When you access a controller function that accepts parameters through url, you can use those parameters just as any other variable, like for example say your url looks like this

```
http://localhost/events/getid/7
```

Then your controller function should look like:

```
public function getid($id = null){
  // $id would take the value of 7
  // then you can use the $id as you please just like any other variable 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the `Conferences` Controller

```
$this->Session->write('conference_id', $this->request->id); // or the variable that stores the conference ID
```

In the `Events` controller

```
$conferenceId = $this->Session->read('conference_id');
```

Of course, on top you need

```
public $components = array('Session');
```